# Awarding 1.5 times the bounty amount?

Tags: support, bounty

If I'm reading the [bounty documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) correctly, 1.5 times the amount will be awarded in this scenario:

- I offer a bounty on my own question.
- New answer A gets 2 upvotes.
- New answer B gets 1 upvote and I accept it.
- I don't manually award the bounty.

According to this paragraph, answer A will be awarded half the bounty amount:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount [...]

According to this paragraph, answer B will be awarded the full bounty amount:

> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

Neither paragraph rules out the other, and they both assert that an amount will be awarded, so 1.5 times the bounty amount will be awarded. Is that correct? Is that the reason it speaks about awarding the bounty "amount" rather than *the bounty*? (The latter sounds like a thing, which only exists once, whereas an *amount* can be multiplied at will.)

Comment: A bounty can only be awarded *once*, not twice. If you accept an answer, then per the quoted text the bounty is awarded to the accepted answer.

Comment: "*Is that the reason it speaks about awarding the bounty "amount" rather than the bounty? (The latter sounds like a thing, which only exists once, whereas an amount can be multiplied at will.)*" the bounty can be for different amounts. E.g., you can put a bounty for 50 or for 500.

Comment: By accepting an answer you _are_ (effectively) awarding the bounty. If you accept an answer B then answer A will get nothing.

Comment: It only talks about the "amount" because in certain cases (the first one you mention) only part of the bounty is awarded.

Comment: Wait, the text *immediately after* your first quote seems to directly answer you: "*the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount **(or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted)**.*" The second quote appears to clarify the text in the brackets.

Comment: @VLAZ the answer (A) is **not** also accepted, so that doesn't apply.

Comment: But the answer (B) *has* been accepted, @KellyBundy , so the bounty is awarded to that. Answer (A) therefore is awarded nothing, as the bounty has been awarded. The logic is which ever is *first* true. Think of the logic like a `Case`/`Switch` statement; only the logical flow for the first true statement is entered.

Comment: @Larnu But that sentence is talking about answer A, not answer B.

Comment: But Answer B has been awarded the bounty, @KellyBundy , so Answer A can't be awarded it.

Comment: You can refer the answer to this [Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for a much more clear explanation of how the bounty is awarded. See the "_What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered? / What is automatic awarding?_" section

Comment: @Larnu *"A bounty can only be awarded once"* - Neither the doc nor I spoke of awarding *the bounty* multiple times, only talking about awarding amounts.

Comment: The document talks about that an answer is awarded, singular, not multiple answer**s**, @KellyBundy . Plus, a little bit of common sense would dictate that reputation is magiced from nothing. *IF* what you propose were possible, then it would most certainly be abused for "reputation laundering".

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine "Effectively" awarding isn't the same as awarding. And the second paragraph says "we", i.e., Stack Overflow, awards. Not me. So "If you do not award" is the case. I think the author of answer A could rightfully complain if they get nothing.

Comment: @Larnu *"If you accept an answer, then per the quoted text the bounty is awarded to the accepted answer."* - Also per the quoted text, half the bounty amount is awarded to the highest voted answer.

Comment: As I stated, *"A bounty can only be awarded once, not twice."*

Comment: @Larnu And as I already stated both in the question and in my earlier comment, neither the doc nor I spoke of awarding the bounty multiple times.

Comment: @Larnu Inb4 "It is awarded once, 50% of it to one answer, 100% to another, that's one bounty split between two answers"

Comment: *"If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (**or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted**)."* the "or" means one or the other, not *both*. The bounty (singular) is awarded to an answer (singular).

Comment: @Larnu You misread that the same way VLAZ did, which I already pointed out: "the answer" there refers to answer A, not answer B. And answer A is **not** also accepted, so that part doesn't apply.

Comment: @Larnu *"The logic is which ever is first true. Think of the logic like a Case/Switch statement; only the logical flow for the first true statement is entered"* - I presented them in the order they're presented on the page. So this argument of yours says that answer A gets awarded and B doesn't (which is the *opposite* of what apparently really happens). And that's actually why under the answer I mentioned that the page should switch the order. But even then it should still also actually somehow say that it's like if-elseif. Currently it's two independent ifs.

Comment: Again, I disagree; but "I'm the one that can't read". ¯⁠\⁠_⁠(⁠ツ⁠)⁠_⁠/⁠¯

Comment: @Larnu Disagree with what? Are you saying your *"first true statement is entered"* argument doesn't say A gets awarded?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) is somewhat clearer on bounty automatic awarding...

> If the author offered the bounty, and accepted an answer that was posted after the bounty was started, that answer is awarded the full bounty.
>
> Otherwise, either all or half of the bounty will be awarded to the highest-scored answer among those which meet all of the following:
>
> - They were posted after the bounty was started, and
> - They have a score of at least 2 (at the time the automatic awarding takes place), and
> - They were not written by the bounty starter.
>
> If the chosen answer was accepted by the question owner, it will receive the full bounty. Otherwise, it will receive half the bounty. If two eligible answers have the same score, the older answer is chosen.

The word otherwise makes it clear that it's either the whole amount or half the amount, but not both.

Comment: Indeed that makes one case rule out the other, unlike the page I linked to (which is the page linked to by the bounty message box of active bounties). I'll accept this, as I asked it as a support question, but I think it would be good if the page I linked to likewise ruled out the first case when the second case applies (and I think it would also be better if that second case came first, as it does on the page you linked to).

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a feature-request question to suggest that the text is changed.

Comment: Maybe I should've done that instead. But looking at the votes and all those comments misreading things, I'm not looking forward to putting effort into it again.

Comment: Lots of comments misreading things are surely a sign that things should be clearer, no? It's not as if meta voting does anything at all anyway.

Comment: @KellyBundy "*But looking at the votes and all those comments misreading things*" seems it's you who insisted your reading was correct when it wasn't. All the "misreads" seem to align with what the actual case is. Which casts a lot of doubt on what was misread in the first place.

Comment: @VLAZ Some of the misreads appear to align with what the actual case is, but as far as I can tell, they're still misreads. They're reading something into it that's not actually there (which is only there on this other page shown by this answer). If I were to post a new question as feature request pointing out that the page isn't saying it, probably it'd get the same response from the same people still reading the same into it that's not there. Also, the misreads about the **"or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted"** are simply wrong (and annoying, especially the second time).

Comment: @KellyBundy "*as I can tell, they're still misreads.*" as opposed to your "correct" read that doesn't actually correctly describe the real situation? Because it didn't. Making it an incorrect read. I should remind you that *you* also read something that's not there - nowhere does it explicitly say that a bounty is awarded multiple times. You read a couple of different paragraphs and interpreted them wrong. We have evidence of it being wrong. But you seem very convinced that it was correct. Stop saying everybody else misreads when we have concrete evidence you definitely did.

Comment: @VLAZ *"Making it an incorrect read"* - No, a correct read of something incorrect. *"nowhere does it explicitly say that a bounty is awarded multiple times"* - It asserts one awarding and it asserts another awarding. Thus it asserts two awardings. *"You read a couple of different paragraphs and interpreted them wrong"* - I interpreted them as they're written. *"We have evidence of it being wrong"* - You mean we have evidence of *the page* being wrong.